# Configuring an asynciohttp_retry client and using later

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a simple sample code aroung `asynchttp_retry`.

```py
import aiohttp
import aiohttp_retry
from aiohttp_retry import RetryClient
import asyncio

retry_statuses = [500, 404]

async def run_http_client():
    retry_options = \
        aiohttp_retry.ExponentialRetry(attempts=3, statuses=retry_statuses)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with RetryClient(session, retry_options=retry_options) as client:
            response = await client.get('https://dummyjson.com/products/20')
            print(await response.text())



asyncio.run(run_http_client())
```

It works. However I would like to be able to split the client instantiation from the request itself.

```py
import aiohttp
import aiohttp_retry
from aiohttp_retry import RetryClient
import asyncio

retry_statuses = [500, 404]


async def get_retrying_http_client():
    retry_options = \
        aiohttp_retry.ExponentialRetry(attempts=3, statuses=retry_statuses)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with RetryClient(session, retry_options=retry_options) as client:
            return client


async def main():
    client = get_retrying_http_client()
    response = client.get('https://dummyjson.com/products/20')
    text = (await response).text()
    print(text)

asyncio.run(main())
```

... I get a `coroutine 'get_retrying_http_client' was never awaited`. If I try to await it, I get `Session is closed`.

I welcome any help as well as some explanations.

I am familiar with promises in JavaScript.

I have used the `threading` library in the past, and I have to admit that I feel that asyncio is just a more painful way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You're not awaiting the coroutines in the `main` function. The `get_retrying_http_client` function needs to be awaited, and inside it, you should await the `client.get` call. Also, you need to use a `ClientSession` as a context manager in the `main` function. You can fix these issues like this:

```
import aiohttp
import aiohttp_retry
from aiohttp_retry import RetryClient
import asyncio

retry_statuses = [500, 404]

async def get_retrying_http_client(session):
    retry_options = aiohttp_retry.ExponentialRetry(attempts=3, statuses=retry_statuses)
    client = RetryClient(session, retry_options=retry_options)
    return client

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        client = await get_retrying_http_client(session)
        response = await client.get('https://dummyjson.com/products/20')
        text = await response.text()
        print(text)

asyncio.run(main())
```

If you'd like to abstract the session management, you can create a class that manages the aiohttp.ClientSession internally and provides an interface to make requests.

```
import aiohttp
import aiohttp_retry
import asyncio

retry_statuses = [500, 404]


class HttpClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self._session = None
        self._retry_options = aiohttp_retry.ExponentialRetry(attempts=3, statuses=retry_statuses)

    async def _get_session(self):
        if not self._session:
            self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
            self._retry_client = aiohttp_retry.RetryClient(self._session, retry_options=self._retry_options)
        return self._retry_client

    async def close(self):
        if self._session:
            await self._session.close()

    async def get(self, url):
        retry_client = await self._get_session()
        response = await retry_client.get(url)
        return response


async def main():
    http_client = HttpClient()
    response = await http_client.get('https://dummyjson.com/products/20')
    text = await response.text()
    print(text)
    await http_client.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input! However this structure forces session to be injected as a dependency. I guess in that structure I must have some level of this for context handling? It doesn't ideally fit my vision about the separation of concerns.

Comment: I updated my answer, my new suggestion meets your comment.